# Error on upgrade to 3.7: Property _transportConfig does not exist

Tags: cakephp

Upgraded CakePHP from 3.5 -> 3.6 -> 3.7. The error message, Property _transportConfig does not exist, is displayed as soon as the application starts in the browser.

Email Transport config in app.php

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
    'className' => 'Smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'username' => '*******@gmail.com',
    'password' => '********************',
    'log' => true,
    'tls' => true
    ],
],
```

Comment: There is some changes in bootstrap.php, app.php (configuration file), and Application.php. Look here https://github.com/cakephp/app and compare with your files

Comment: @Salines - Thank you. Comparing the bootstrap.php and Application.php found the issues and resolved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found some information in the [migration guide](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-7-migration-guide.html), here is a solution that may work;

---

First, you need to add this to your bootstrap file

```
use Cake\Mailer\TransportFactory;
```

then replace

```
Email::setConfigTransport(Configure::consume('EmailTransport'));
```

by

```
TransportFactory::setConfig(Configure::consume('EmailTransport'));
```

finally you might consider updating the debugger via composer :

```
λ composer require --update-with-dependencies "cakephp/debug_kit"
```

Might not be the best way to, but it worked for me!

Comment: Now that CakePHP4 is out there you should update the DebugKit in your composer.json manually:
`"cakephp/debug_kit": "^3.17.0",`